# Run e2e tests with testcafe on bitbucket

Tags: reactjs, bitbucket, e2e-testing, testcafe, bitbucket-pipelines

So I wrote some e2e tests with testcafe and they run perfectly on my local machine. Now I want them to run in a bitbucket pipeline, but I'm no able to get it to work.

My `bitbucket-pipeline.yml` looks like this

```
image: testcafe/testcafe

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm ci
          - /opt/testcafe/docker/testcafe-docker.sh 'firefox:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage' test/**
```

The error message I get on the pipeline:

```
A request to "http://127.0.0.1:3000/" has failed.
Use quarantine mode to perform additional attempts to execute this test.

You can find troubleshooting information for this issue at "https://go.devexpress.com/TestCafe_FAQ_ARequestHasFailed.aspx".

Error details:
Failed to find a DNS-record for the resource at"http://127.0.0.1:3000/".
Browser: Firefox 78.0 / Linux 0.0
```

Does anybody know what causes this exception and how to solve it?

Comment: Likely you need to start your web app server via the [--app](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#-a-command---app-command) option. How do you start it in the local environment?

Comment: @AndreyBelym I think the issue is not related to the web app server as the web app server runs on port 8081. The request fails on port 3000 which is the port TestCafe uses to perform testing.
I start the web app server by pulling a docker image, launching it in the background and waiting for 30 seconds until the e2e tests are started.

Comment: This error means that TestCafe failed to load a page specified as a test or a fixture page. It should be specified using the web app port, not the TestCafe port. Could you please make sure that your web app port is 8081 and you use it in the test that throws the error?

Comment: @AndreyBelym All the tests are running fine, except for the first one. No matter what the first testcase is (even if I switch them) the first one fails (all the others run).

Comment: This may be a bug. Could you please [submit](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) a bug report to TestCafe with detailed information?

Comment: It is now working in quarantine mode. I added -q and the pipeline runs now.